# Erro em código de IMC

Tags: java

Tenho o código abaixo, que calcula IMC, podem me dizer qual o erro dele?

Segue o código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Paciente {

        public static double calcularIMC(double P,double A){
            double imc;
            imc=P/(A*A);
            return imc;

    }
        public static String diagnostico(){
            double A,P,imc;
            Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Entre com o valor de sua altura em metros :");
            A=entrada.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Entre com o valor de seu peso em Kg");
            P=entrada.nextInt();
            imc=Paciente.calcularIMC(P,A);

            if (imc<16.0){
                System.out.println("Baixo peso muito grave");
            }
            if (16<imc<16.99){
                System.out.println("Baixo peso grave");
            }
            if (17<imc<18.49){
                System.out.println("Baixo peso");

            }
            if (18.50<imc<24.99){
                System.out.println("Peso norma");
            }
            if(25<imc<29.99){
                System.out.println("Sobrepeso");
            }
            if(30<imc<34.99){
                System.out.println("Obesidade grau I");
            }
            if(35<imc<39.99){
                System.out.println("Obesidade grau II");
            }
            if(imc>=40){
                System.out.println("Obesidade grau II(obesidade morbida");
```

Comment: Qual erro que dá?

Comment: Amigo especifique seu erro, ninguem daqui é adivinho. Considere editar a pergunta e colocar o qual o erro que dá ao tentar fazer esse calculo, e de uma olhada na area de ajuda http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para poder criar perguntas com melhor formatação e mais específicas.

Answer (score 2):

Seu código tem vários erros de semântica, a forma correta de comparar não é `16<imc<16.99`, e sim `16< imc && imc <16.99`, são duas comparações sendo feitas ao mesmo tempo.

Dei uma melhorada em algumas coisas, como o método *main* que você alterou o nome, e sem ele a sua classe não iria iniciar. Porém, tem muita coisa ainda pra melhorar, talvez com mais estudos, você vá aprimorando e consertando, ou fornecendo mais informações na pergunta.

```
public class Paciente {

    public static double calcularIMC(double P,double A){
            return P/(A*A);
    }

    public static void diagnostico(double imc){

            if (imc < 16.0){
                System.out.println("Baixo peso muito grave");
            }
            if (16< imc && imc <16.99){
                System.out.println("Baixo peso grave");
            }
            if (17<imc && imc <18.49){
                System.out.println("Baixo peso");

            }
            if (18.50< imc && imc < 24.99){
                System.out.println("Peso norma");
            }
            if(25<imc && imc <29.99){
                System.out.println("Sobrepeso");
            }
            if(30<imc && imc <34.99){
                System.out.println("Obesidade grau I");
            }
            if(35<imc && imc <39.99){
                System.out.println("Obesidade grau II");
            }
            if(imc>=40){
                System.out.println("Obesidade grau II(obesidade morbida");
            }
        }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
            double A,P, imc;
            Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Entre com o valor de sua altura em metros :");
            A = entrada.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Entre com o valor de seu peso em Kg");
            P = entrada.nextDouble();
            diagnostico(calcularIMC(P,A));
    }
}
```

Veja funcionando no [**IDEONE**](https://ideone.com/Rsiejv)